# Call function is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(function() {
    var previous_page = "<?=$_SESSION["previous_page"]?>";
    if (previous_page == "bar_settings")
        $.club_settings();

    $.club_settings = function() {
        $(".bar_settings").fadeIn(1000);
        $(".bar_photos").hide();
        $(".bar_activities").hide();
        $(".bar_campaigns").hide();
        $(".etkinlik_ekle").hide();
        $(".kampanya_ekle").hide();
    }

})(jQuery);
```

I got an error that is `$.club_settings` is not a function. How can i call `$.club_settings` in a if condition ?

Comment: Because you do not define it before trying to call it. You are creating an anonymous function, not a named one that gets hoisted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're defining the function *after* you call it.  Switch around the code like so:

```
$(function() {
    $.club_settings = function() {
        $(".bar_settings").fadeIn(1000);
        $(".bar_photos").hide();
        $(".bar_activities").hide();
        $(".bar_campaigns").hide();
        $(".etkinlik_ekle").hide();
        $(".kampanya_ekle").hide();
    }

    var previous_page = "<?=$_SESSION["previous_page"]?>";
    if (previous_page == "bar_settings")
        $.club_settings();


})(jQuery);
```

Comment: omg, how i can missed it :D thanks a lot, i waste too much time for this :(

Answer (score 0):

[JavaScript only hoists declarations, not initializations.](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp)

The reference above displays how variables are hoisted but it works for functions too.

```js
$(function() {
   var previous_page = "<?=$_SESSION["previous_page"]?>";
   if (previous_page == "bar_settings")
     club_settings();

   function club_settings() {
     $(".bar_settings").fadeIn(1000);
     $(".bar_photos").hide();
     $(".bar_activities").hide();
     $(".bar_campaigns").hide();
     $(".etkinlik_ekle").hide();
     $(".kampanya_ekle").hide();
   }
})(jQuery);
```

The drawback would be is that it would be found in your `$` variable which may lead to codes elsewhere breaking. But that could be another question.

Trying to resolve this by doing `$.club_settings() = function club_settings() { ...` will not work unless you reorder your codes as suggested by Mike